Can't get attribute "Preset" (custom class) on <module '__main__' from "/path"
I am writing a flask app and have a setup function that will initialise a list of objects and write them to a file using pickle. The setup function works fine when I run the script through the terminal, however trying to load the pickled file results in the title
error:
Can't get attribute "Preset" (custom class) on  <module '__main__' 
from '/Users/angoose/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/.venv/bin/Flask'.

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pickle


global filename
filename = "static/presets.pkl"



class Preset:
    def __init__(self, name: str, displayName: str, layout: str, stringData: list):
        self.name = name.upper()
        self.displayName = displayName
        self.layout = layout
        self.stringData = stringData
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name},{self.displayName},{self.layout},{self.stringData}"


def setup() -> None:
    try:
        with open(filename, "rb") as f:
            presets = pickle.load(f)
        if not type(presets) == list or not len(presets) == 3:
            raise EOFError
        else:
            print("hurray!")
    except EOFError:
        # file is empty
        six = Preset("Fender", "Stratocaster", "6", ['E', 'A', 'D', 'G', 'B', 'E'])
        four = Preset("JP60", "JP60", "4+2", ['E', 'A', 'D', 'G', 'B', 'E'])
        three = Preset("LPStandard", "Les Paul Standard", "3+3", ['Eb', 'Ab', 'Db', 'Gb', 'Bb', 'Eb'])
        with open(filename, "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump([six, three, four], f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)


def save(obj) -> None | int:
    # File mode "ab" for "append bytes"
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        presets = pickle.load(f)
        if not type(presets) == list:
            return 1

    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        presets.append(obj)
        pickle.dump(presets, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    return None


def load():
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        return pickle.load(f)



setup()
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    name = request.args.get("name")
    return render_template("index.html", name=name)


@app.route("/tune")
def tune():
    x = Preset("jp60", "Stella","4+2","['E','A','D','G','B','E']")
    save(x)
    y = load()



    return render_template("tune.html", test=y)


@app.route("/metronome")
def metronome():
    return render_template("metronome.html")


I have looked around to see if others have had this issue and it looks like most times the issue is that pickle cannot find the class to reconstruct it, as pickle does not save the class itself. I have so far tried: using dill instead, moving the class definition around, checking if Flask has the right requirements (pickle module) and none have worked. The fact that pickle can work correctly in normal python (commenting out the flask sections) makes me think that this is probably flask and pickle not mixing well, which I also searched and found little to help.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

is this code which makes problem?

Sorry for that, I ran into a different issue with Flask and I had to rewrite how I loaded the flask app. Instead of using Flask run --debug in the terminal I had to use if name == "main": app.run(port=5000, debug=True). The good news is that all is working. Thank you!

if you resolved your problem then you can describe it (with details) as answer below - maybe it will be useful for other people. And you may mark your answer as accepted, and later you can upvote your answer.
